# scrapy + selenium: <a> tag has no href, but content is loaded by javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, scrapy

I'm almost there with my first try of using scrapy, selenium to collect data from website with javascript loaded content.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

class FreePlayersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'free_players'
    allowed_domains = ['www.forge-db.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.forge-db.com/fr/fr11/players/?server=fr11']
    driver = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/alain/Documents/repository/web/foe-python/chromedriver')
        self.driver.get('https://forge-db.com/fr/fr11/players/?server=fr11')

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        #time.sleep(1)
        sel = Selector(text = self.driver.page_source)

        players = sel.xpath('.//table/tbody/tr')

        for player in players:
            joueur = player.xpath('.//td[3]/a/text()').get()
            guilde = player.xpath('.//td[4]/a/text()').get()

            yield {
                'player' : joueur,
                'guild' : guilde
            }

        next_page_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="paginate_button next"]')
       

        if next_page_btn:
            time.sleep(2)
            next_page_btn.click()
            yield scrapy.Request(url = self.start_urls, callback=self.parse)

        # Close the selenium driver, so in fact it closes the testing browser
        self.driver.quit()

    def parse_players(self):
        pass
```

I want to collect user names and their relative guild and output to a csv file.
For now my issue is to proceed to NEXT PAGE and to parse again the content loaded by javascript.

if i'm able to simulate click on NEXT  tag, i'm not 100% sure that code will proceed all pages and i'm not able to parse the new content using the same function.

Any idea how could i solve this issue ?
thx.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using selenium, you should try recreate the request to update the table. If you look closely at the HTML under chrometools. You can see that the request is made with parameters and a response is sent back with the data in a nice structured format.

Please see [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#topics-reproducing-requests) with regards to dynamic content in scrapy. As it explains the first step to think about is it necessary to recreate browser activity ? Or can I get the information I need from reverse engineering HTTP get requests. Sometimes the information is hidden with `<script></script>` tags and you can use some regex or some string methods to gain what you want. Rendering the page and then using browser activity should be thought of as a last step.

Now before I go into some background on reverse engineering the requests, this website you're trying to get information from requires only to reverse engineer the HTTP requests.

### Reverse Engineering HTTP requests in Scrapy

Now in terms of the actual web itself we can use chrome devtools by right clicking inspect on a page. Clicking the network tab allows you to see all requests the browser makes to render the page. In this case you want to see what happens when you click next.

Image1: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqx0o.jpg)

Here you can see all the requests made when you click next on the page. I always look for the biggest sized response as that'll most likely have your data.

Image2: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7txm.jpg)

Here you can see the request headers/params etc... things you need to make a proper HTTP request. We can see that the referring URL is actually getplayers.php with all the params to get the next page added on. If you scroll down you can see all the same parameters it sends to getplayers.php. Keep this in mind, sometimes we need to send headers, cookies and parameters.

Image3: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHYFG.jpg)

Here is the preview of the data we would get back from the server if we make the correct request, it's a nice neat format which is great for scraping.

Now You could copy the headers and parameters, cookies here into scrapy, but after a bit of searching and it's always worth checking this first, if just by passing in an HTTP request with the url will you get the data you want then that is the simplest way.

In this case it's true and infact you get in a nice need format with all the data.

### Code example

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['forge-db.com']
    
    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.forge-db.com/fr/fr11/getPlayers.php?'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url)
    def parse(self,response):
        for row in response.json()['data']:
           yield {'name':row[2],'guild':row[3] }
```

#### Settings

In settings.py, you need to set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` The site doesn't want you to access this data so we need to set it to false. Be careful, you could end getting banned from the server.

I would also suggest a couple of other settings to be respectful and cache the results so if you want to play around with this large dataset you don't hammer the server.

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
```

### Comments on the code

We make a request to `https://www.forge-db.com/fr/fr11/getPlayers.php?` and if you were to print the response you get all the data from the table, it's quite a lot... Now it looks like it's in json format so we use scrapy's new feature to handle json and convert into a python dictionary. `response.json()` be sure that you have uptodate scrapy to take advantage of this. Otherwise you could use the json library that python provides to do the same thing.

Now you have to look at the preview data abit here but the individual rows are within `response.json()['data'][i]` where i in the row of data. The name and guild are within `response.json()['data'][i][2]` and `response.json()['data'][i][3]`. So looping over every `response.json()['data']`and grabbing the name and guild.

If the data wasn't so structured as it is here and it needed modifying I would strongly urge you to use Items or ItemLoaders for creating the fields that you can then output the data. You can modifying the extracted data more easily with ItemLoaders and you can interact with duplicates items etc using a pipeline. These are just some thoughts for in the future, I almost never use yielding a dictionary for extracting data particularly large datasets.